# scaling down and repeating a texture in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have quite a large plane with a set displacement map and scale which I do not want to be changed. I simply want the loaded texture to apply to that mesh without it having to scale up so largely.

Currently, a floor texture doesn't look like a floor as it has been upscaled to suit the large plane.
How would I be able to scale down the texture and multiply it across the plane so it looks more like actual terrain?

```
const tilesNormalMap = textureLoader.load(
  "./textures/Stylized_Stone_Floor_005_normal.jpg"
);
```

```
function createGround() {
  let disMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./models/Heightmap.png");

  disMap.wrapS = disMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  disMap.repeat.set(4, 2);

  const groundMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: tilesBaseColor,
    normalMap: tilesNormalMap,
    displacementMap: disMap,
    displacementScale: 2
  });

  const groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 300, 800, 800);
  let groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, groundMat);
  scene.add(groundMesh);
  groundMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  groundMesh.position.y -= 1.5;
```

I tried using the .repeat method as shown below but i can't figure out how this would be implemented

```
 tilesBaseColor.repeat.set(0.9, 0.9);
 tilesBaseColor.offset.set(0.001, 0.001);
```

a photo of the current ground texture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvLH3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what you want to achieve does currently not work with `three.js` since  it's only possible to a have a single uv transform for all textures (except for light and ao map). And `map` has priority in your case so you can't have different repeat settings for the displacement map. Related issue at GitHub: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9457

> Currently, a floor texture doesn't look like a floor as it has been upscaled to suit the large plane. How would I be able to scale down the texture and multiply it across the plane so it looks more like actual terrain?

In this case, you have to use repeat values great `1` otherwise you zoom into the texture. Do it like in the following live example:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init().then(render);

async function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  const texture = await loader.loadAsync('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg');
  
  // repeat settings
  
  texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  texture.repeat.set(2, 2);

  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.148/build/three.min.js"></script>
```